# Convert pandas to numpy.ndarray for sparse.hstack

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sparse-matrix

I try to solve next problem

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import sparse

X1 = sparse.rand(10, 10000) 
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'a': range(10)})
```

In fact, I get X1 from TfidfVectorizer but let go of the code for the sake of brevity

I want to apply sparse.hstack to use both variables in a regression.
I convert pandas to numpy.ndarray as below

```
X2 = df['a'].as_matrix()
type(X2)
numpy.ndarray
X = sparse.hstack((X1,X2))
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-9493e3833c5d> in <module>()
----> 1 X = sparse.hstack((X1,X2))

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\construct.py in hstack(blocks, format, dtype)
    462 
    463     """
--> 464     return bmat([blocks], format=format, dtype=dtype)
    465 
    466 

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\construct.py in bmat(blocks, format, dtype)
    579                 elif brow_lengths[i] != A.shape[0]:
    580                     raise ValueError('blocks[%d,:] has incompatible '
--> 581                                      'row dimensions' % i)
    582 
    583                 if bcol_lengths[j] == 0:

ValueError: blocks[0,:] has incompatible row dimensions
```

What's wrong?

Comment: from the doc: `Parameters: 
tup : sequence of ndarrays
All arrays must have the same shape along all but the second axis.` so your array does not have the same shape. you can check by `X1.shape()` and `X2.shape()`

Comment: X1.shape (10, 10000) X2.shape (10,)

Comment: I think it would need at least 1 row for this to work.

Comment: it works X2= np.random.random((10, 1))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done as below. It works

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import sparse

X1 = sparse.rand(10, 10000)
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'a': range(10)})

X2 = df['a'].reset_index()
X2 = X2.iloc[:,[1]].values

X = sparse.hstack((X1,X2))
```

Comment: Or working directly with a `np.arange`: `sparse.hstack([X1, np.arange(10)[:,None]])`.  The idea is to make a column matrix.  Look at `sparse.bmat` to see more of what this `hstack` does.

Answer (score 0):

your arrays must have the same first dimension size and must contain at least 1 row each.

you can check that by `X1.shape()` and `X2.shape()`